# Using try/catch to verify JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When parsing expected JSON input, I use a try catch statement to determine whether or not the response body is indeed JSON, and store this in a variable:

```
let noParseErr = true;
try {
  JSON.parse(body);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  noParseErr = false;
} finally {
  if (noParseErr) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: JSON.Parse throws an `Error` upon failure, this is the only way of doing this.

Comment: You are not changing the variable `noParseErr`, so, yes, a better approach would be changing it's value to `false` when an error occurs

Comment: why are you define a variable with true once and then just check it with an if? I'm talking about noParseErr

Comment: you have try and catch blocks... you dont need an "noParseErr" variable at all

Comment: Sorry I changed the code now, forgot to change the variable on catch err

Comment: I personally detest using try/catch to determine whether or not something is valid, but sometimes it just is the only reasonable option.  I'd just create a function though, like `function isValidJson(json)` and have try return true and catch return false.  It's just a bit tidier than checking it where you use it, and reusable for _**when**_ you want to do the same thing later.